# Index HashMap using keys as fields names. HibernateSearch

Tags: spring, lucene, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I want to index a `map<String, Integer>` by using the map keys as field names. I have found that by default I can index only keys or values (`BuiltinContainerExtractors.MAP_KEY/MAP_VALUES`), so I am trying to implement my own binder/bridge. That is my code:

```
public class SomeEntity {

    @Transient
    @PropertyBinding(binder = @PropertyBinderRef(type = ConceptDistancePropertyBinder.class))
    public Map<String, Integer> getRelated() {
        return ...;
    }
}

public class ConceptDistancePropertyBinder implements PropertyBinder {
    @Override
    public void bind(PropertyBindingContext context) {
        context.dependencies().useRootOnly();
        IndexSchemaElement schemaElement = context.indexSchemaElement();
        IndexSchemaObjectField conceptDistanceField = schemaElement.objectField("conceptDistance");
        conceptDistanceField.fieldTemplate(
                "conceptDistanceTemplate",
                fieldTypeFactory -> fieldTypeFactory.asString().analyzer("default")
        );
        final ConceptDistancePropertyBridge bridge = new ConceptDistancePropertyBridge(conceptDistanceField.toReference());
        context.bridge(Map.class, bridge);
    }
}


public class ConceptDistancePropertyBridge implements PropertyBridge<Map> {

    private final IndexObjectFieldReference conceptDistanceFieldReference;

    public ConceptDistancePropertyBridge(IndexObjectFieldReference conceptDistanceFieldReference) {
        this.conceptDistanceFieldReference = conceptDistanceFieldReference;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DocumentElement target, Map bridgedElement, PropertyBridgeWriteContext context) {
        Map<String, Integer> relatedDistanceWithOtherConcepts = (Map<String, Integer>) bridgedElement;
        DocumentElement indexedUserMetadata = target.addObject(conceptDistanceFieldReference);
        relatedDistanceWithOtherConcepts
                .forEach((field, value) -> indexedUserMetadata.addValue(field, field));
    }
}
```

And I've got an exception:

```
    Hibernate ORM mapping: 
    type 'com.odysseusinc.prometheus.concept.entity.ConceptEntity': 
        failures: 
          - HSEARCH800007: Unable to resolve path '.related' to a persisted attribute in Hibernate ORM metadata. If this path points to a transient attribute, use @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = ...) to specify which persisted attributes it is derived from. See the reference documentation for more information.
```

`context.dependencies().useRootOnly()` does not help. I also tried to use `context.dependencies().use("somefield")` and but got another exception

```
    Hibernate ORM mapping: 
    type 'com.odysseusinc.prometheus.concept.entity.ConceptEntity': 
        path '.related': 
            failures: 
              - HSEARCH700078: No readable property named 'filedName' on type 'java.lang.Integer'
```

I extracted all necessary code and put it the GitHub https://github.com/YaroslavTir/map-index
that really straightforward, and the exception appear after start `Application.main`

Comment: "_No readable property named 'filedName'_": Just to check: `filedName` looks like a typo - should it be `fieldName`?

Comment: @andrewjames thank you for the replay. That is a typo, but it does not change a situation, I get the same exception without the typo too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message is telling you:

> If this path points to a transient attribute, use @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = ...) to specify which persisted attributes it is derived from. See the reference documentation for more information.

In particular, see [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-derivedfrom).

In short, add the annotation to `getRelated()` so that Hibernate Search knows which properties you derived your map from:

```java
public class SomeEntity {

    @Transient
    @PropertyBinding(binder = @PropertyBinderRef(type = ConceptDistancePropertyBinder.class))
    @IndexingDependency(
        derivedFrom = {
            @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "someProperty1")),
            @ObjectPath({@PropertyValue(propertyName = "someProperty2"), @PropertyValue(propertyName = "someNestedProperty")})
        },
        extraction = @ContainerExtraction(extract = ContainerExtract.NO)
    )
    public Map<String, Integer> getRelated() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Note that in your case, you have to specify explicitly in `@IndexingDependency` that *the entire map* is "derived", not just the values (which is what Hibernate Search would target by default, as you noticed). That's why you need `extraction = @ContainerExtraction(extract = ContainerExtract.NO)`: this essentially tells Hibernate Search "this metadata applies to the whole map, not just to the values".

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer. The `IndexingDependency` was the first thing that I tried. That does not help. I think we should configure it using `context.dependencies().use` I wrote a simple application to reproduce it. https://github.com/YaroslavTir/map-index

Comment: @yaroslavTir Right... That's because the `@IndexingDependency`, just like any other Hibernate Search annotation, will target the the *values* of `.map` by default. You need to add `extraction = @ContainerExtraction(extract = ContainerExtract.NO)` to `@IndexingDependency` in order to clarify that you mean the *whole map* is derived. I know it's a bit weird, but it makes more sense if you consider how everything else works. Anyway, I updated my answer.

Comment: I created [HSEARCH-4271](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4271) to hopefully address this quirk in a future version of Hibernate Search.

Comment: ContainerExtract.NO solve the issue, thank you for the answer